# Icon not showing on published .NET application

Tags: visual-studio, icons, publish

I've got a VB.Net application that I'm finally now publishing (i.e. compiling into a self-installing .exe using Visual Studio's 'Publish Now' button), instead of just using the Debug output. It works fine, and installs fine, but the icon shown for the installed program is not the program's icon, just a generic icon.

Under my Application settings, the Icon option is set to the icon I want- but the 'publish now' functions appear to be ignoring this setting.

I'm on Visual Studio 2015 and my online searches for an answer only turn up some several-years-old answers which refer to options and settings which are no longer present, or at least, not where they used to be. The most promising page referred to a 'BuildAction' setting on the icon file, but it doesn't correspond to any option I can see in VS2015.

What am I missing here please? What else do I need to do to make sure the icon that displays on the taskbar or Start menu for my installed program is the icon I want?

Comment: When you "Publish" the app, are you sure that the publish process is copying the image/icon to the appropriate folder?  Not sure, but I think if you look at the properties of the image/icon you may need to set copy to true.

Answer (score 0):

Part-answering my own question here (apologies if that's the incorrect protocol) but I realised the problem isn't nearly as extensive as I had imagined. When I install the compiled application from Setup.exe onto the PC that I developed it on, the proper icon doesn't appear. However when I take the same Setup.exe and install it on a different PC, the icon appears exactly as I would expect- which is fine for now.